# Bintrees method example

Tags: python, foreach

I'm sure this is a trivial question, but it's late.  I've recently starting teaching myself Python because of a machine learning course that I'm taking.  I usually use C++, so with Python, I just want to use packages and not redo things I've done in C++ in Python.  That being said, I just installed `bintrees 2.0.1` which has an AVL Tree.

I'm trying to do an 'inorder' traversal running a class function at each node.  The documentation has this line `foreach(f, [order]) -> visit all nodes of tree (0 = ‘inorder’, -1 = ‘preorder’ or +1 = ‘postorder’) and call f(k, v) for each node, O(n)`.  I've looked all over for a syntactic example of using this tree function, however, I cannot get it to work.  I've tried the following with 'var' being the AVL tree datastructure:
`foreach(var, 0): method()`
`var.foreach(method(), 0)`
`foreach(var, 0).method()`
Nothing works. Maybe I'm tired, but I can't find an example anywhere on the web either.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should probably provide some example code (i.e. how you construct your `var` object and an example `method()` function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [function signature](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/bintrees) should be `var.foreach(method, 0)` where the method is of the form `f(k, v)` and the integer (-1, 0, +1) defines how you order the nodes.

The function `f(k, v)` should use the key (k) and the value (v) for each node.

An example is:

```
from bintrees import AVLTree

d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

t = AVLTree(d)

def foo(k, v):
    print k*v

t.foreach(foo)
# a
# bb
# ccc
```

Comment: This answered it exactly.  The problem was my function didn't have the proper signature.